# Image Fetching From The Server and Saving to Documents Folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, nsdata

I am taking the image as NSData and saving it to Documents Folder.

The problem is, when i try to save it Documents Folder, it saves 2 out of 4, or 3 out of 4. It saves  randomly.

I could not figure out where the problem is, since after first failure of saving, the second try may be successful for a particular image.

Could you please help me?

```
 NSData * response = [appDel.serviceHelper serviceCall:@"" withURL:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Application/GetImage/%@",appDel.appPage.editorServiceURL,ID]];

 NSError *error = nil;
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
 NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Images"];


if(response !=nil)
{
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
    {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
    }

    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:response];

    NSString *pngFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",dataPath,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",fileName]];

    NSData *data1;
    if([pngFilePath rangeOfString:@".png"].location !=NSNotFound)
    {
        data1 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
        NSLog(@"png Image");

    }
    else if([pngFilePath rangeOfString:@".jpg"].location !=NSNotFound)
    {
        data1 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1.0)];
        NSLog(@"jpg Image");

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"another extension Image");

    }


    [data1 writeToFile:pngFilePath atomically:YES];

    //[appDel.fileHelper writeToFile:response withFileName:fileName];
}
```

Comment: I guess you need to add the code you are using, otherwise it's hard to see what could be the problem.

Comment: @MarkGibson i have added my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try taking the response as NSMutableDictionary instead of NSData. That might show you what the exception is.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #define   DocumentsPath                 [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]

 NSURLSession *defaultNSURLSession ;

 CallMethod:   

 [self downloadImage_WithImageName:@"HERE YOUR FILENAME" FromFileURL:@"HERE IMAGE URL"];

-(void) downloadImage_WithImageName:(NSString *)imageName FromFileURL:(NSString *)fileURL{


 NSString *dataPath = [DocumentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Images"];
 NSString *filePath=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/Images/%@",DocumentsPath,imageName];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
{
    //NSLog(@"Downloading %@ to %@...", fileURL, filePath);


    NSURLRequest *request=[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileURL]];
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downTask = [defaultNSURLSession downloadTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]; //Create folder

            NSError *err = nil;

            if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtURL:location toURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath] error:&err]) {
               //Reload your UITableview or UICollectionView
            }else{
                NSLog(@"move error %@", error);
            }

        }else{
            NSLog(@"error %@",error);
        }

    }];
    [downTask resume];

} else {
    NSLog(@"%@ already exists. not downloading.", imageName);
}

}
```